# Pheatmap sometimes not rendering in Shiny

Tags: shiny, pheatmap

I have a complex Shiny app with hundreds of reactive elements. The problem is that sometimes pheatmap plots don't render, and I have to restart the app to make it work. This has been the case with all different pheatmap plots with no shared data or code, across different R versions, and both on Shiny Server and RStudio Connect. When this happens it affects all users, so it's not anything to do with my system. There is nothing in the logs and I haven't been able to find anything by following the reactivity trace. There are probably a dozen plotting packages used and it's only pheatmap that has this problem. I can't provide a reproducible example, because it works 90+% of the time. Any hints at all on how this can be?

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71239465/r-shiny-plotlyoutput-and-plotoutput-conflict) related question. I think it's a bug. I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/raivokolde/pheatmap/issues/85).

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with the same issue and ironically enough, clearing the "plots" tab in rstudio before running your app seems to resolve the problem. You can also `dev.off()` any previous graphics generated.